# How to Fill form and submit using windows application

Tags: c#, html, windows

People here wonder because its too old and already asked..
but here is my problem arises.

You see two input fields with same name?

**HTML CODE**

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" name="textbox" />
<form name="tax280" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>
<input type="text" name="textbox" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i use below code. I think values gone set in hidden attribute.

```
 HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
 doc.GetElementById("textbox").SetAttribute("Value", "text");
```

In Simple How to set values required textbox alone i can't find any solution please help.

please visit this link and click link that page contains https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp

Comment: `GetElementById` ... Id.

Comment: works on name also but  there are 2 text field with same name. i need to set text what field i need @HristoYankov

Comment: No it doesn't. `getElementsByName` works on names.

Comment: How could i post a video for you? @HristoYankov

Comment: Yeah i want to do it. please help @HristoYankov

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vdpd02um/

Comment: @AnbarasanAnbu the core problem with your question is that you should use another function.

Comment: @bradbury9 i don't understand

Comment: We do not use [solved] title hacks here, please do not edit that in again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day I found answer for my question.

when there is 2 or more text input fields its easy to fill data on both the fields.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" name="textbox" />
    <form name="tax280" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="textbox" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and windows form application code is below.

```
 var elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
            {
                if (element.Name.Contains("textbox"))
                {
                    element.SetAttribute("Value", "my text");
                }
            }
```

it works but the problem is data fill in both the text field..

Thank you for the helping hearts those are replied for my problem. 
:D

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to set an ID. Because `GetElementById` works with an `id` attribute, not `name`.

```
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vdpd02um/

Comment: no it works but my problem is there are 2 text field with same name. i need to set text what field i need.

Comment: No, the problem is that your field has no ID.

Comment: in clear to that some of the text fields sets because no hidden text fields on same name.

Comment: If you want to access them, control should have unique identifiers. They can share `name`, but they should have unique `ID`attributes and you should access them via `.getElemebtByID(controlid)`

Comment: go to this site https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp and view source @bradbury9

Answer (score 1):

If you have this HTML, please note the difference between `id` and `name` attributes:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="firstTextbox" />
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="secondTextbox" />
```

You can access them via `getElementsByName` (ByName returns an array):

```
var fistTextBox = document.getElementsByName('textbox')[0];
var secondTextBox = document.getElementsByName('textbox')[1];
```

BUT to avoid problems you should use:

```
var fistTextBox = document.getElementById('firstTextbox');
var secondTextBox = document.getElementById('secondTextbox');
```

Because `.getElementById`return just one item.

Comment: understank my question. i like to fill form using windows application not in javascript